# Should I omit my grades from my CV for retail/entry jobs?

Tags: resume, job-search, retail

So I have been applying for jobs for three weeks so far, mostly retail. I have not received a single response as of yet. I admit I don't have much experience.

I did pretty well in my A-levels(high-school) but would that be cause for them to filter me out? Is it acceptable for me not to mention my grades?. It's pretty disappointing to not hear back from any of them and I feel like I am grasping at straws to figure out why.

Comment: Maybe they are looking for something other than just high school grades.

Comment: Which entry level position are you applying for in retail?

Comment: Are you talking about a shop office or about the headquarter? From what I heard is that retail shops often are not good organized, so that a response will take several weeks. Sometimes they even forget to reply if you send it by mail. (Not an answer because it's hearsay.)

Comment: What country is this? In the USA it's not typical to put your actual grades or GPA on your resume.

Comment: I am applying for mainly retail assistant roles.

I live in the UK.

Answer (score 4):

If you have no experience, getting your first job can be a frustrating experience, but it's usually a matter of dusting yourself off and trying again. Widen your net of possible industries. Volunteer.

Include your grades if you think someone would be impressed by them. The fact that you haven't gotten an offer yet likely has nothing to do with your grades, and everything to do with timing, luck, or losing out to others with more experience.

Keep trying, and think of creative ways to get working experience, even if it's not directly related to the jobs you want right now.